# How to change dotnet framework from core to .NET Framework in powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core

I have installed both .NET Core and .NET Framework on my machine. Currently if I type `dotnet --version` it shows that I'm using .NET Core. How can I swap from .NET Core to .NET Framework in my powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotnet` is part of .NET Core. It's the command line interface to .NET Core (only). There's no `dotnet` command for .NET Framework.

You can use the `dotnet` command to build applications for .NET Framework. Edit your csproj and change it to target .NET Framework (`TargetFramework` of `net472`, for example) and then use `dotnet build`. That is still using the `dotnet` from .NET Core but targetting and using assets from .NET Framework.

Another way to use .NET Framework is to use `msbuild.exe` directly. That always ends up using .NET Framework. But there's no `dotnet` equivalents (`dotnet run`).

Comment: If there is no CLI for .NET Framework how can I run my dll files or build a project?

Comment: AFAIK, for building, you can use `msbuild.exe`. If your build produces executibles, you can run them directly.

Comment: But what if I need to have dll files not exe. How can I run my project after publishing.

Answer (score 0):

"dotnet" is .Net Core cli tool. You can read about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools)